# React Native Build Error for Android after Gradle Upgrade

Tags: react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > Could not generate a proxy class for class com.android.build.gradle.tasks.BuildArtifactReportTask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is want I did to followed to fix.

I had already updated java.

But the important thing is to update JAVA_HOME variable which `react-native-cli` checks when executing its build process. I have had the latest 1.8.0_191 update but still the build failed.

So this is how I solved it. By making sure my react-native-cli refers to latest JDK by means of env variable.

Answer (score 6):

I got the same problem and solved it by update my JDK version from 1.8.0_20 to 1.8.0_171. You may try update your JDK version as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had your same problem, I had JDK 1.8.05 and upgrade to 1.8.0_172, delete your .gradle folder of the project, and run again react-native run-android.. have fun